# Why am I getting "invalid syntax" error while importing universe module from openAI

Tags: python, openai-gym

When I import `universe` module from openAI. I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kunal/Desktop/OpenAi/openAI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/universe/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from universe import error, envs
  File "/home/kunal/Desktop/OpenAi/openAI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/universe/envs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import universe.envs.vnc_env
  File "/home/kunal/Desktop/OpenAi/openAI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/universe/envs/vnc_env.py", line 11, in <module>
    from universe.envs import diagnostics
  File "/home/kunal/Desktop/OpenAi/openAI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/universe/envs/diagnostics.py", line 94
    async = self.qr_pool.apply_async(self.method, (self._last_img, time.time(), available_at))
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why am I getting this? and how can I solve this?

Comment: `async` was made into a keyword to support [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutines) in Python 3.5, so from the little code shown in your question, it looks like it may be due to an attempt to run older code with a newer version of the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libosmesa6-dev xvfb ffmpeg curl patchelf libglfw3 libglfw3-dev cmake zlib1g zlib1g-dev swig
```

After that reinstall the gym using:

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git
cd gym
pip install -e .
```