# Error while attempting to import openai's universe

Tags: python

While importing openai's universe, i get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/calvin/Desktop/universe-test/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import universe
  File "/Users/calvin/universe/universe/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from universe import error, envs
  File "/Users/calvin/universe/universe/envs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import universe.envs.vnc_env
  File "/Users/calvin/universe/universe/envs/vnc_env.py", line 11, in <module>
    from universe.envs import diagnostics
  File "/Users/calvin/universe/universe/envs/diagnostics.py", line 94
    async = self.qr_pool.apply_async(self.method, (self._last_img, time.time(), available_at))
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried downloading a different version of gym, reinstalling universe, and nothing works. I have python 3.8.5 64-bit. My operating system is macOS Catalina 10.15.6. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372092/why-am-i-getting-invalid-syntax-error-while-importing-universe-module-from-ope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`async` is now a special keyword](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-coroutine-declaration-syntax), and as such, can't be used as a variable name.

That library appears to be made for Python pre-3.5. I believe your only options are:

- Use a older version of Python 3 (`async` was intrduced in 3.5).
- Edit the local copy of the library file to change the name to something else.
- Check to see if there are any updates/forks to the library that fix that issue.

Comment: Awesome! this solved the problem! For anyone else with this problem, download python 3.5.0. It works!